# How can I make border-left height?

Tags: html, css

How can I make border-left  height property ihave only one attribute h4 and i want to add border left side with height how this can be possible ? in also title here so we can't put height to  so can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense as written. Could you re-write it to be clearer?

Comment: could you share the HTML markup and CSS?

Comment: Border has width, not height. This might help you: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-width

Answer (score 1):

As a border will always have the same height as the element it is a border for, you can't control the height other than changing the height of the element itself. But you can create a pseudo element on the element and set the height of that element and give the pseudo element a border.

```
h4:before {
    height: 15px;
    width: 0px;
    content: ' ';
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    position/top/left as you see fit.
}
```

Comment: Aron Cederholm thank's for help i have get what i have actually want's

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible to set a hight for a border, it will be as tall as the element. Maybe use a image instead as thats something you can control.

You could do something like this if you wanted.

[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/e4hD5/)

You can see the first `<div>` setting the height for everything and the second had the same border line. `.test1` has a dotted line and `.test2` has a solid line, this shows you they are on the same line. Using that it makes it look like your setting the border for `.test1` but you really have another `<div>` setting the border.

Or like this in your terms. [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ALHjE/)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Borders can have thickness, not height. Their height is dependent on the container's height they are applied to. So in example if your H4 has height of 40px, your border will be 40px in height. Try using line-height as an addition to modify your h4 element :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any property by which you can control the height of a border. After all as the name suggests "it is a border" but what you can do is give or remove padding to your h4 element to control the height of your border

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any Height property of border in CSS, instead of border you can add Image of border with height you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this..

```
    <h2>
        <div style="border-left:1px solid black;height:yourheight:width:5px;position:absolute;">&nbsp;
        </div>
        //your title name
    </h2>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Give space between the line and title as you wish..

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way!

```
<div style="border-left:1px solid black;
height:0px;
width: 0px;
position:absolute;"> 

Lorem Upsim etc.

</div>
```